# How Do I Change the Font of a UIlabel?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

How can I set font of UILabel to one that is not in interface builder list?

I have the fonts file. How do I use it in app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://kgriff.posterous.com/45359635 is a great tutorial on accomplishing this.

Basically, add a key to the info.plist file, and REMEMBER to use the font name that is assigned via the meta attribute in your font's info file, NOT the actual ttf name.

In the plist, add a key "UIAppFonts". Set its value to an array that includes the string "FontName.ttf"

Of course make sure you have added the ttf to the project.

Now in your app, use:

`[UIFont fontWithName:@"Font Name as in your Font Book, not the file name" size:12.0f]`

Answer (score 0):

Changing the font of a label is done by using the [`UIFont`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html) object:

`self.timeLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:(NSString *) size:(CGFloat)];`

Comment: I did not down vote, but probably because your answer did not answer the question. He asked how to use a custom font in a UILabel, **custom** being the important word.

Comment: @Shaharyar I downvoted your answer because, as pointed out by Justin, it doesn't answer the question asked. Your answer illustrates how to set a label's font to a named font but says nothing about how to import a custom font and use it. Hope that provides the clarification you were looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change your font through this code:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[label setFrame:CGRectMake(8, 10, 150 ,20)];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.text = [tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:15];
```